# Example and description for @requestpart

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

The requirement is a user will upload files to spring boot (ReST request) using angular. The ReST interface store the file into gitlab for further processing. Using @RequestPart annotation, content with a different name will be retrieved from a request and placed into Gitlab. Implementation will look like as follows:

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Upload java files into Gitlab")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = "application/json")
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, response = CustomResponse.class, message = "Success"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, response = ErrorResponse.class, message = "Bad Request"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, response = ErrorResponse.class, message = "Internal Server Error") })

    public CustomResponse uploadJava(
            @ApiParam(value = "Interface", required = true)
            @RequestPart(name = "interface", required = true) final MultipartFile interfaceClass,

            @ApiParam(value = "Java Class", required = false) 
            @RequestPart(name = "javaClass", required = false) final MultipartFile javaClass) {
        return null;
    }
```

My question is,

1. How to add description and example for the above. (Similar to
   RequestParam)
2. How to set content type for each file.

Note:

1. I tried modifying @RequestParam instead of @RequestPart. In this
   case, the second file ("javaclass") alone pushed to spring boot.
2. My current POM

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Regards